# Uncertain as how to test complex method

Tags: java, unit-tests, junit

I have a class which handles when a CardView's drag gets started.

I've been looking at tutorials for JUnit and I can't seem to find out how to start testing this method.

```
public class DragDetectedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
private Stacks stacks;
private NextCards nextCards;
private Table gameTable;

public DragDetectedHandler(Stacks stacks, NextCards nextCards, Table gameTable) {
    this.stacks = stacks;
    this.nextCards = nextCards;
    this.gameTable = gameTable;
}

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    System.out.println("Dragdetected");
    CardPane source = (CardPane) mouseEvent.getSource();
    Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
    ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();

    //IF from stacks or nextCards, we only need to deal with dragging 1 card
    if (stacks.has(source) || nextCards.has(source) || gameTable.getColumns()[gameTable.getColumnIndex(source)].hasNextShown(source)) {
        db.setDragView(source.getCard().getImage());
        cc.putString(String.valueOf(source.getCard().getNumber()));
        source.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        //Else we need to copy the whole stack to the dragboard
        Integer xy[] = gameTable.getXY(source);
        if(xy != null){
            Image ghostStack = gameTable.getStackImage(xy[0], xy[1]);
            db.setDragView(ghostStack);

            cc.putString("Stack");
        }
        gameTable.toggleShownCardsFromColumn(source);
    }

    db.setContent(cc);


}

}
```

So far I have come up with this:

```
class DragDetectedHandlerTest {

@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void handle() {
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    PatienceController pc = new PatienceController();

    Stacks stacks = new Stacks();
    NextCards nextCards = new NextCards(stackPane, pc);
    Table table = new Table(pc);

    DragDetectedHandler handler = new DragDetectedHandler(stacks,nextCards, table);



}

}
```

Problem is I don't know what to assert for or how to get there. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to consider is that you're going to need multiple tests to cover this unit.

Here's how I'd approach it:

- Each defined condition gets a test: so there'll be a test method for dragging from stack; one for dragging from the next cards, one for dragging from the next cards column, and one for none of the above.
- Each test method needs to be split into at least two test methods: one to assert that the correct number of cards are moved, and one to assert that the state of the board after the move is as expected.
- Each object the method uses needs to be instantiated with a mock instance rather than the actual object so that you're not pulling dependencies into your tests.
- If the code you're testing is not using interfaces to provide the functionality, you'll need to manually create your mock object instances with enough information to exercise your tests.
- You will also need to create a mock mouse event with the exact properties you need.

With all that configured, I'd structure my tests this way:

```
@Test
void DragFromStacksMovesOneCard()
{
     // Create the mouse event with the appropriate properties
     // Use helper methods to instantiate the mock objects
     // This includes instantiating the clipboard content

     // call handle(mouseEvent) with the newly created event

     // Assert that the number of cards in the clipboard content has increased by one.
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Now I know where to start.